# assignment from incompatible pointer type in ssh

Tags: c, pointers, ssh, struct

I need your help.. 
I build 3 structs :
song, listofSong and musicAlbum.

I get the message warning in ssh: "assignment from incompatible pointer type"
according to the two rows that I wrote next to them: // problem

```
typedef struct   
{

    char* nameSong;
    char* nameSinger;
    int lenghtOfSong;
    struct song *next;
    struct song *prev;

} song;

typedef struct
{

    song* head;
    song* tail;

} listOfsong;

typedef struct
{

    int yearOfpublication;
    listOfsong* listOfSongs;
    int numbersOfSongs;

} musicAlbum;

song* SongCreate()
{

    song *songInput =(song*) malloc(sizeof(song));
    //free
    songInput->nameSong = StringName();
    songInput->nameSinger = StringName();
    scanf("%d", &songInput->lenghtOfSong);
    songInput->next = NULL;
    songInput->prev = NULL;
    return songInput;

}

void AddSongToList(musicAlbum *pmusicAlbum)
{

    if (pmusicAlbum->listOfSongs == NULL)
    {
        pmusicAlbum->listOfSongs = (listOfsong*)malloc(sizeof(listOfsong));
        song *newSong=SongCreate();
        pmusicAlbum->listOfSongs->head = newSong;
        pmusicAlbum->listOfSongs->tail = newSong;
    }
    else
    {
        song *newSong = SongCreate();
        newSong->prev = pmusicAlbum->listOfSongs->tail;// problem
        pmusicAlbum->listOfSongs->tail->next = newSong; // problem
        pmusicAlbum->listOfSongs->tail = newSong;
    }

}
```

anyone knows what does it means? 
it is appear in other places in my project

thank you .

Comment: Please don't do this `pmusicAlbum->listOfSongs->tail->next` unless you are sure that there will be no `NULL` dereference or uninitalized pointer dereference. Besides it's ugly and hard to follow for readers.

Comment: What exactly did you type in to get that warning? It has little to do with `ssh`. What line number(s) was (were) indicated in the warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
typedef struct   
{
    char* nameSong;
    char* nameSinger;
    int lenghtOfSong;
    struct song *next;
    struct song *prev;
} song;
```

to

```
typedef struct song song;

struct song
{
    char* nameSong;
    char* nameSinger;
    int lenghtOfSong;
    struct song *next;
    struct song *prev;
};
```